# Do the following sentences mean the same?

Tags: grammar

1) The sun has been shining all day.

2) The sun has shone all day.

I know that the two analogous statements:

1) We have been living in Brazil for ten years.

2) We have lived in Brazil for ten years.

have the same meaning that we lived in Brazil for 10 years and we are still living there.
So,the statements at the top ought to have identical meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean the same thing, the sun started to shine this morning and it is still shining now.